# [error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1' in Azure Pipeline

Tags: jmeter, azure-devops, cicd, jenkins-pipeline

Getting error as 2024-03-06T14:40:10.8848644Z jmeter -g Results.jtl -o htmlReport
2024-03-06T14:40:10.9326661Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2024-03-06T14:40:10.9654622Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a_temp\6ddde4de-8a4f-43bd-873a-a69bbf34b8cd.cmd""
2024-03-06T14:40:12.6419288Z An error occurred: Cannot read test results file : Results.jtl
2024-03-06T14:40:12.6858284Z errorlevel=1
2024-03-06T14:40:12.6863140Z Press any key to continue . . .
2024-03-06T14:40:12.7701636Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.

In Azure Pipeline

[image]
[image]
[image]

could anyone please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You either need to:

1. Publish the `Result.jtl` file in the step where you run the test and download it in the step where you're generating reporting dashboard
2. Or generate the dashboard just after test execution:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o resultHtml
   ```

More information:

- [How to share file(s) between YAML Stages in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55694545/how-to-share-files-between-yaml-stages-in-azure-devops)
- [Generation after load test](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_after_load_test)
- [JMeter Non-GUI Mode: Useful Tips](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode)